# How do I get names of subdirectories of a directory purely in python?

Tags: python, subdirectory

I dont want to use commands or any similar module that uses unix shell.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please read about the `os` module, then revise your question to ask something specific about the `os` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this recursively, going down a tree visiting all the directories, then you can use os.walk like this:

```
  for root, directories, files in os.walk("c:\\"):
    doSomething
```

If you only want the subdirectories you can either call walk once:

```
  directories = os.walk("c:\\").next()[1]
```

Or do some sort of filter like this (walk is more stylish/portable):

```
  filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir("c:\\"+ x), os.listdir("c:\\"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.walk()`:

```
import os, os.path

def walk_directories(src):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for dir in dirs:
            print os.path.join(root, dir)

walk_directories(r'c:\temp')
```